# R Lottery function: What's wrong with my work?

Tags: r, math, probability

I have here a question from an online quiz set by my university (already submitted, so I'm just curious to know what the discrepancy is)
[image]

As you can see, there is a set.seed which I have put s into (as requested),and this will give me a certain, exact string of numbers every time, as long as the seed is the same.

However, the people who made the question have run it with s = 1, but as seen below, we have obtained different results:
[image]

Could anyone tell me why this is happening? Have my searches about the sample() function overlooked something? Any help in understanding this for the future would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: You have not specified "equal probability". `1:59` are not equal numbers.

Comment: I get `51 46 38 17 54 19`. Do you get the same if you try it again?

Comment: Can you please post the code and results in a text format rather than as images/snapshots?

Comment: @Roland What should I put for probability then?
EDIT: I have checked again and found that I should have been using rep() instead of c(). Thanks for the help in realising this, Roland!

Comment: You should have left `prob=NULL` then each number in your sequence 1 to 59 would have had an equal chance of being selected. To to match the expected results used `prob=rep(1, 59)` to create a vector of fifty-nine "1"

Comment: Since this is for a class, the most important thing to say is that you should have read ?sample before doing the problem.  If you get in that habit you will save a lot of angst.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the UK lottery, all balls are presumed to have equal probability.  As others pointed out, you specify different probability weights.  Ball "1" has weight 1, i.e., is unlikely to be drawn, while higher numbers are more probable, up to weight 59 on ball "59".  Dave2e gave the correct answer: as your assignment *requires* that you state the probability, you cannot rely on the default `prob=NULL`, and must specify a vector of 59 equal numbers.  My R gives your "Expected" result:

```
> set.seed(1)
> sample(59, 6, prob=rep(1,59))
[1] 17 24 36 55 13 54
```